# use datamart against multiple databases

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence, datamart

I'm currently working on a project of building a data mart using SSIS 2008 r2 from  ERP database.

These datamarts will have to be used in every database that has the same structure (same tables/fields).

The problem is that the source table name changes based on the database connected to. But the table structure (metadata) does not change between those environments.

For example, 
Database 1 *item* table name is **company_name1$item**
Database 2 *item* table name is **company_name2$item**

I'm looking for a solution that makes the datamart can be used for both databases.

I did some research; I found that my solution can be like explained in the picture
[image]

As you in the diagram picture, there are steps to follow to build the datamart:

- To build a datamart, you will to extract the informations and process
  them through ETL to have the desired datamart. This procedure needs
  to be applied to all databases
- This procedure can be done by a table in the erp database called
  object This table has all kind of informations about the database
  tables but the most useful fields are table id,table name and company
  name

[image]

Now, I want to use this table id, Name Company to select the proper table without having to selected data based on table name but there no linking between object table and other tables, so you kind of need to create a some kind of code or something to be able to create the link. 
*In a nut shell, when I want to use package for a databse , I have insert is the company name and the package will be run to fill my datamart.*

As some suggested, I should use a sql procedure of this type
USE YourDataBaseName;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyData
    @aCompany NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @tbl_ID INT = 0
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @aQuery NVARCHAR(4000) 

    SELECT @tableName = [Name]
    FROM [object]
    WHERE [Company Name] = @aCompany AND [ID] = @tbl_ID

    SET @aQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName
    EXEC(@aQuery)
GO
```

Other one which was also interesting, **said that  SSIS allows for the use of a variable name in your source and destinations. I just simply need to provide the mechanism for making that value change. Perhaps that's a foreach enumerator containing the data flow or a parameter set at run-time.** 
Both suggested solution are great but still not clear on how to do that , I hope now that I have explained my question, I  would get a more specific answer

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking for. If you are building a data mart, you need to build a standard data model for your mart, then define an extract / load / transform process to load the data from all your source databases (for each database, given that it appears the schemas are different in each source database).

Comment: thanks for your answer, so what I understand is that in each dataflow, all I have to do is change the table name ?

Comment: I too am rather confused by your question, but what I am reading is that the source or destination table name changes based on the database it is connected to. As you have clearly stated, the meta data (table structure) does not change between these environments, you are in luck. SSIS allows for the use of a variable name in your source and destinations. You simply need to provide the mechanism for making that value change. Perhaps that's a foreach enumerator containing the data flow or a parameter set at run-time. Without more detail, it'd be hard to prescribe a solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! and yeah, I think your suggestion would help me.I tried to add more details about my problem.I would like to elaborate how to provide the mechanism to value change?

Comment: I agree with @billinkc. If you have same stucture and you want to reuse your package just set table name as variable and enumerate through database list. You have to create list of your databases and containing tables or if you can calculate table name from db name it's even easier. I used to create form that allow me choose database that I want to use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.I'm still learning ssis so could you please explain by calculating table name from db name ?